# can you access a mongoose created database from mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

noob node.js, Express and MongoDB here, running on Ubuntu 14; I created a mongoose in an express/nodejs app database via:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
...
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/firstExpress");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  age: Number 
});

var Users = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);

app.post('/users', function(req, res){
  var b = req.body;
  new Users({
    name: b.name,
    email: b.email,
    age: b.age
  }).save(function(err, userDoc){
    if (err) res.json(err);
    res.redirect('/users/' + userDoc.name);
  });
});

app.get('/users/:name', function(req, res){
  Users.find({ name: req.param.name }, function(err, docs){
    if (err){ 
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      res.json(doc[0]);
    } 
  });
});
```

making a post request works, and adds a user to the userbase. Is there any way to view this db in mongo from the shell?

i.e. from

```
sudo mongo --smallfiles
```

when I run this and execute the command

```
show dbs
```

I cannot see the database that the express app made, nor can I see it in any collections contained in any db. yet, when I restart the node app and make no post requests, but call a get on the users, I get the list of users I had previously created. Could someone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the connection url `mongodb://localhost/firstExpress`, I can assume that the name of your database is `firstExpress`.

So, just log in your mongo server with `mongo firstExpress`. To see your collections, use `show collections`, and you'll see them.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Robomongo** (http://robomongo.org/ Shell-centric cross-platform MongoDB management tool) to see your database collections.

Add new connection to localhost:27017 and you will see all your collections with data